# Set up GPS and location services on blackberry

Tags: blackberry

i need to get latitude and longitude using gps on blackberry. When i check in simulator, i got the default latitude 43 and longitude 80. When i check on device, i got latitude 0.0 and longitude 0.0.

I check on device, option-> Device ->Location setting.

Gps data source is Device GPS and location services turns to location on.

But till, latitude and longitude  values are 0.0.

Is there any settings to enable the gps? Pls help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be the problem of GPS lock. please check the gps lock is obtained.

thanks

Comment: Hi. how to check the gps lock or not?

Comment: in device under location settings there will be  location deatails(location data). where you can see latitude, longitude and when details are updated.

Comment: I've seen , but the values are zero.

Comment: Then the the gpslock is not obtained.

Comment: then what should i do to get values?

Comment: it depend on your location. go to some location where you know as gps is availabile and give a clear sky view  to device.